# Does Dunn Test require multiple comparisons correction?

Tags: nonparametric, post-hoc, kruskal-wallis-test, dunn-test

If I compared 8 groups with a single Kruskal-Wallis test and it came back positive (<0.05), and then was interested in conducting a Dunn Test to determine which pairs differed between each other, should I apply a corresponding correction (lets say a Bonferroni correction and divide each p-value by 28)? Or does the use of Dunn's test already protect from the issue of multiple comparisons?

Comment: This might be one of those questions where the answer actually depends on which software you use. It can be implemented either way.

Comment: I would recommend reading this article - http://www.soph.uab.edu/Statgenetics/People/MBeasley/Courses/Saville-MultipleComparionsPracticalSolution-1990.pdf David Saville offers a different viewpoint, that the alpha not be adjusted. Maintain the alpha, if you want to be conservative, simply evaluate the multiple comparisons at lower alpha levels - .01, .005, .001. This only applies if your software has not done the adjustment for you already. Also, for what it's worth, a Bonferonni correction would involve multiplying the p-values not dividing.

Comment: @user7019377 I am using this package: https://gist.github.com/alimuldal/fbb19b73fa25423f02e8

Comment: It says in the source code that it corrects for multiple testing